# PHP count time and divide in daytime/nighttime

Tags: php, timestamp

I have been trying to figure this out for a week now. My wife has started a new taxi-company and she asked me to code a simple webpage for here where she could press a button to save a timestamp, then the press is again when she gets off work, it then creates a second timestamp

I have an MYSQL database with rows containing the start time and stop time. I have managed to use the diff function to see how much time it is between the two timestamps but now comes the tricky part.

Since it's different payments at different times of the day I need to divide the time at a shortened time.

Up to 19:00 she works "daytime" and after that, she works "nighttime" until 06:00 the other day, then there is "weekend daytime" and "weekend nighttime" as well.

So if she creates a timestamp whit the date and time: 2018-08-08 06:30 and then another timestamp at 2018-08-08 21:00, then I need a script that puts these data in ex "$daytimehours = 12" "$daytimeminutes = 30" and "$nighttimehours = 3" "$nighttimeminutes = 0"

I have managed to create a script that almost works, but it is several pages long, and it contains one if-statement for each different scenario daytime-nighttime, nighttime-daytime etc.

So do anyone has a good idea on how to solve this? or maybe just point me in the right direction. I would be happy to pay some money to get this to work.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Almaty');
$endDate     = '2018-08-08 21:00';
$startDate   = '2018-08-08 06:30';

$nightmare   = date('Y-m-d 19:00');
$startDay     = date('Y-m-d 06:00');

$diffMorning = strtotime($nightmare) - strtotime($startDate);
$diffNight   = strtotime($endDate)   - strtotime($nightmare);

echo gmdate('H:i', $diffMorning) . "\n"; // this is the difference from start day till 19:00
echo gmdate('H:i', $diffNight); // this is the difference on nightmare

$total = $diffMorning + $diffNight;
echo intval($total/3600) . " hours \n";
echo $total%3600/60 . " minutes \n";
echo $total%3600%60 . ' seconds';
```

You can check via [online compiler](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f9658eb079810c68573e99bdcb5a1569e2180c05)

Comment: also you can contact me on skype: kenzhegalin.serik

Comment: Thank you. Iwill try this when I get home :)

Comment: Okey so I got your code working now, but when I want to get a totalt amout of time worked on ie "daytime" I use this code:

$dagtidhelgtotal = $dagtidhelgtotal + $dagtidhelg;

But it does not take minutes in consideration, it just adds up all the hours.

Comment: This seems good for a single day but how do you get total between dates.
Post your table structure. We might be able to do it entirely in SQL.

Comment: Isnt there a wey for me to just convert ie 08:30 to minutes, in this case 510 minutes?

Comment: @Andreas, sure `gmdate('H:i', $time)`

Answer (score 0):

given two dates stated as:

```
$endDate     = '2018-08-08 21:00'; 
$startDate   = '2018-08-08 06:30';
```

you can use the PHP Date extension to achieve the difference like this:

```
$start = date_create($startDate);
$end = date_create($endDate);
$boundnight = clone($end);
$boundnight->setTime(19,00);

$total_duration = date_diff($end,$start);//total duration from start to end
$day_duration = date_diff($boundnight,$start);//daytime duration
$night_duration = date_diff($end,$boundnight);// nighttime duration
```

you can use the format method to print a human readable string this way:

```
$total_duration=$total_duration->format('%H:%I');
$day_duration=$day_duration->format('%H:%I');
$night_duration=$night_duration->format('%H:%I');
```

At this step there is nothing left but you say you want to convert each  duration in minutes.So let's build a function :

```
function toMinute($duration){
    return (count($x=explode(':',$duration))==2?($x[0]*60+$x[1]):false);
}
```

Then you can use it this way:

```
$total_duration = toMinute($total_duration);
$day_duration = toMinute($day_duration);
$night_duration = toMinute($night_duration);
```

The output of 
`var_dump($total_duration,$day_duration,$night_duration)` at this step is:

```
int(870)
int(750)
int(120)
```